# How can I make an operating system as small as possible but still provide the basic functions?

Tags: kernel

I would like to use the make nconfig command to create an operating system based on the Linux 4.4.49 Kernel. I would like it to be able to carry out the basic functions of an operating system, such as driver compatibility, but be as small as possible. What things should I include or exclude for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That entirely depends what functionality you need. “Basic functions” is far too vague for anybody to give a useful answer.

Comment: Well,  typical operating systems can provide basic driver support and displays. So I would like it to have the same basic functions as any other Linux distribution. But my question is if there are any unnecessary items in the configuration menu that could be disregarded?  I would like to make the kernel as minimal as possible whilst still being able to carry out functions such as display, using drivers and other necessary tools.

Comment: That's still vague. Everybody has their own ideas as to what is an absolutely indispensible basic function and what is superfluous bloat that nobody in their right mind would want. People code features for a reason, and distributions include them for a reason. If you want to make a minimal kernel for a specific application, then you have to figure out what *your application* needs and doesn't need.

Comment: Well, I can't really simplify what I want any more so I'll go through the menu and see what I need.

Comment: I think a more interesting question is, what exactly is the minimum functionality the kernel can provide and move from there. For example, does the kernel run the console as a necessity or can we run the kernel without it? What other user interaction does the kernel provide, it's not like they're obvious or common sense.